# Partial View Wizard with Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Looked many things up, but never posted before. Here's my situation. Any help would be most appreciated.

I've got a wizard with numerous screens with an associated navigation bar made using CSS. As users click from screen to screen, the navigation reflects the current wizard page the user is on. Each screen has different inputs to be collected. Database reads and writes are required during the render and submission of each page.

Here's the catch. Not every page is required. Only required pages are displayed in the navigation and the required information is stored in the database.

My goal is to reduce the number of database queries by dividing the navigation and remaining input into two separate partials. This way I don't have to render the navigation between each screen eliminating the single query every time between screens.

How would I submit the form of the current screen, render the partial view of the next screen, and yet update the query string to reflect the current partial view as well? This way if the user refreshes the page, they get the current screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like pre-optimization. How do you know you're going to have a problem with your navigation because of the database?

Why not separate out your navigation and [output cache it](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)?

If you bound determined to change the url without changing the content you need to use [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) and if you need a fall back for browsers that don't support that you can use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).